# tfidf vectorizer giving wrong results

Tags: python, tfidfvectorizer

I have documents like below

```
1             NAME LASTNAME DOB CITY
2                     NAME ADDRESS CITY
3            NAME LASTNAME ADDRESS CITY
4    NAME LASTNAME ADDRESS CITY PINCODE
5                  NAME ADDRESS PINCODE
```

and `TfidfVectorizer` gave below values

```
    address      city      dob  employername  lastname  mobile      name  \
0  0.000000  0.306476  0.68835           0.0  0.553393     0.0  0.354969   
1  0.573214  0.535492  0.00000           0.0  0.000000     0.0  0.620221   
2  0.412083  0.384964  0.00000           0.0  0.695116     0.0  0.445875   
3  0.357479  0.333954  0.00000           0.0  0.603009     0.0  0.386795   
4  0.493437  0.000000  0.00000           0.0  0.000000     0.0  0.533901   

   phone   pincode  
0    0.0  0.000000  
1    0.0  0.000000  
2    0.0  0.000000  
3    0.0  0.497447  
4    0.0  0.686637
```

From above, both documents 1 & 3 have 'name' term and also no. of terms is same in both documents, so tf(name) should be same in both cases. Also idf would be same. But why 'name' feature has different tfidf values in both documents?

Please help me understand this.

I actually have many documents and applied tfidf on all of those, given above are top 5 records of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `norm='l2'` is the default setting. It means it is L2 normalizing the matrix so that all values lie between 0 and 1.

You can turn that off by using `norm=None` and you will get the same values for Tfidf -

```
doc = ["NAME LASTNAME DOB CITY", "NAME ADDRESS CITY", 
       "NAME LASTNAME ADDRESS CITY", 
       "NAME LASTNAME ADDRESS CITY PINCODE", "NAME ADDRESS PINCODE"]

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

vec = TfidfVectorizer(norm=None)
tf_idf = vec.fit_transform(doc)

print(vec.get_feature_names())
print(tf_idf.todense())
```

Output

```
['address', 'city', 'dob', 'lastname', 'name', 'pincode']
[[ 0.          1.18232156  2.09861229  1.40546511  1.          0.        ]
 [ 1.18232156  1.18232156  0.          0.          1.          0.        ]
 [ 1.18232156  1.18232156  0.          1.40546511  1.          0.        ]
 [ 1.18232156  1.18232156  0.          1.40546511  1.          1.69314718]
 [ 1.18232156  0.          0.          0.          1.          1.69314718]]
```

**P.S:** It is always better to normalize your feature matrix

**UPDATE**
With L2 Norm, each number is divided with the square root of the sum of the squares of the rows. Example - For row 1:column 4, 1.40546511 will be divided by the square root of the sum of squares of row 1. Here is code that shows this -

```
import math
first_doc = tf_idf.todense()[0].tolist()[0]
l2 = math.sqrt(sum([i*i for i in first_doc]))
print(l2)
print([i/l2 for i in first_doc])
```

Output

```
2.9626660243635254
[0.0, 0.39907351927997176, 0.7083526362438907, 0.4743920160255332, 0.3375338265523302, 0.0]
```

In this case I just manually calculated what `TfidfVectorizer` would have done with `norm='l2'`. Notice how all values are between 0 and 1. This is one of the techniques to normalize your data. Normalization helps algorithms to converge quicker and have more accuracy. I hope this clears it up.

Comment: Thanks that works. Thnx a ton for the quick response.

Comment: Can you please tell me what is l2norm and which is ideal to use with or without l2norm?

Comment: @My3 It is advised that you USE l2 norm

Comment: Cool! that clears all my doubts. Thank you so much :)